# position top inside position fixed div always return the same value for every element jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a fixed sidebar which floats all over the page when it is opened, the sidebar has a fixed height of the body and the content inside the sidebar is set to `overflow-y: auto;` so that when the content is more than sidebar height it adds a scroll!

Now there are some fields inside the sidebar that needs to be validated when the sidebar form is submitted, due to scroll the field that is showing the error might be up and the user might be at the bottom of the sidebar so i need to add a `scrollTop`

the problem is when is try to get the position of the element it always returns the same value even for separate fields, here's my code!

**HTML**

```
  <form id="add_staff" method="post" action="{{url('saveStaff')}}" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="changepicture_overlay_container changepicture_overlay_container1 changepicture_overlay_container_hidden">
        <div class="changepicture">

            <div class="wrapper">

                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
                        <h2>Add Staff</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content">

                    <div class="status-float">


                        <div class="staff-checkbox inactive-box">
                            (In-Active)
                        </div>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="active" class="cbx hidden" name="status" value="1" />
                        <label for="active" class="lbl"></label>
                    </div>


                    <div class="sidebar-fields">

                        <div class="sidebar-fields-block">
                            <label for="name">Enter Full Name<span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="required_remove" id="name" name="name"/>
                            <p class="error">This Field is Required!</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sidebar-fields-block">
                            <label for="email">Enter Email<span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="required_remove" id="email" name="email"/>
                            <p class="error">This Field is Required!</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sidebar-fields-block">
                            <label for="password">Generate Password<span>*</span></label>
                            <input id="copied_link" class="required_remove" type="text" name="password"/>
                            <p class="error">This Field is Required!</p>
                            <i class="fas fa-undo fa-flip-horizontal generate-password"></i>
                            <i data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copied_link" class="far fa-copy clipboard"></i>

                        </div>

                        <div class="sidebar-fields-block">
                            <label for="phone">Enter Phone<span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="required_remove" id="phone" name="phone"/>
                            <p class="error">This Field is Required!</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sidebar-fields-block">
                            <label for="dob">Enter Date of Birth</label>
                            <input type="text" id="dob" name="DOB"/>
                            <p class="error">This Field is Required!</p>
                            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sidebar-fields-block">
                            <label for="gender">Enter Gender</label>
                            <select id="gender" name="gender">
                                <option value="1">Male</option>
                                <option value="2">Female</option>
                            </select>
                            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sidebar-fields-block">
                            <label for="staff">Enter Staff Department</label>
                            <select id="staff" name="department_id">

                            </select>
                            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sidebar-fields-block">
                            <label for="lang0">Enter Primary language</label>
                            <input type="text" name="language[]"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="append-language">

                        </div>

                        <div class="addmore">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                            <a>Add</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="admin-staff">
                        <div class="checkbox-sidebar">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Admin" class="cbx hidden" name="role" value="Admin"/>
                            <label for="Admin" class="lbl"></label>
                            <span>Admin</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox-sidebar">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Staff" class="cbx hidden" name="role" value="Staff"/>
                            <label for="Staff" class="lbl"></label>
                            <span>Staff</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-footer">
                    <div class="btn-box">
                        <a class="back"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>BACK</a>
                        <button type="submit">Create</button>
                        <a class="cancel">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.changepicture_overlay_container {
    transition: right 0.3s ease;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.changepicture_overlay_container_hidden .changepicture{
    width: 580px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    right: -580px;
    transition: right 0.3s ease;
    top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #808896;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.changepicture_overlay_container_visible .content{
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 140px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
.changepicture_overlay_container2 .content{
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-bottom: 250px;
}
.changepicture_overlay_container_visible .changepicture, .changepicture_overlay_container .overlay{
    right: 0px;
    transition: right 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-height:100%;
}
.changepicture_overlay_container_visible .overlay {
    width: calc(100% - 580px);
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(209,212,217, 0.9);
    right: 580px;
    transition: right 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#add_staff").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $flag=true;
                if(!$("#name").val()){
                    $("#name").next("p.error").show();
                    $("#name").addClass("border-error");
                    taketotop($("#name"));
                    $flag=false;
                }
                if(!$("#email").val()){
                    $("#email").next("p.error").show();
                    $("#email").addClass("border-error");
                    taketotop($("#email"));
                    $flag=false;
                }
                if($("#email").val() && !validateEmail($("#email").val())){
                    $("#email").next("p.error").html("Please Enter Correct Email");
                    $("#email").next("p.error").show();
                    $("#email").addClass("border-error");
                    $flag=false;
                }
                if(!$("#copied_link").val()){
                    $("#copied_link").next("p.error").show();
                    $("#copied_link").addClass("border-error");
                    $flag=false;
                }
                if(!$("#phone").val()){
                    $("#phone").next("p.error").show();
                    $("#phone").addClass("border-error");
                    $flag=false;
                }
                if($flag){

                    $object = {
                        "_token": $('.getCsrfToken').val(),
                        "email": $("#email").val()
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: "{{url('car_get_with_stock_number_leads_full_data')}}",
                        data:$object,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            loader_start();
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            loader_end();

                            //below line goes for if email exist
                            $("#email").next("p.error").html("Email Already Exist!");
                            $("#email").next("p.error").show();
                            $("#email").addClass("border-error");
                            //below line goes for if email exist

                            //else
                            //$("#add_staff")[0].submit();
                            //else
                        }
                    });
                }

            });

function taketotop($element){
                alert($element.position().top);
//                $('#sidebar_0 .changepicture_overlay_container .changepicture').animate({
//                    scrollTop: $("#sidebar_0 "+$element.trim()+"").position().top
//                }, 'slow');
            }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfw4h916/9/)

the above function is where the problem occurs i have alert the position top of both Name and Email Fields but it always returns the same value i.e 22, i dont know whats the problem any help?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve], that also includes the stylesheet.

Comment: @misorude i have updated my answer please have a look now

Comment: Please provide the actual, client-side code - your HTML above still seems to contain server-side template loops etc. No one here has your server-side setup available, so no one will be able to produce the exact output either. Preferably show a live example somewhere, so that we can inspect it without having to create a run-able example ourselves.

Comment: my sincere apologies i have adjusted the html and provided the working fiddle please have a look!

Comment: In that fiddle I get two alerts with _different_ position values shown.

Comment: yes but when i run it on my project it returns only 22 for both, the code is the same i have just not included CSS

Comment: So then all you did now was show an example that does _not_ reproduce the problem - how is that supposed to be helpful? _“the code is the same i have just not included CSS”_ - well maybe the CSS _causes_ the problem, have you thought about that? Considering what Nomis already mentioned in their answer, that is very likely - `position` gives you the position relative to the offset _parent_ - and what the offset parent is, depends on the applied styling.

Comment: that makes sense i would look into it in more detail thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) get the, well, position of the element **relative to its parent**. Try [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead or, if not possible, try getting the parent position (and/or the parent's parent).

**Edit :** as stated by others in comment, without an easy-to-test snippet it's hard to be sure, but it should look like something like that :

```
$('.content').position().top+
$('.sidebar-fields').position().top+
$element.closest('.sidebar-fields-block').position().top
```

And it **should** return something you cant use. There are many ways to improve it (some loop, adding or removing some elements position), but as-is it's the most precise answer I can give.

**Edit after the JSFiddle and some fiddling :** here you go !

```
$('.changepicture').scrollTop($('.changepicture').scrollTop()+$element.offset().top);
```

With it you adapt your positioning to the actual scroll. Much more robust ! Still beware of calling your function `taketotop` multiple time since it will move the scroll before the user can see it. You could for example add a little condition here :

```
$("#email").addClass("border-error");
if($flag)taketotop($("#email"));
```

Then `taketotop` wouldn't be called twice if already triggered by a name error.

Comment: offset is used when you want to get the position of the element relative to the body, i have a fixed div which has no concern with the body so i cannot use offset whereas position is used to get the position of the element relative to the parent

Comment: Then you'll need to get the position of the element positioned in the scroll element (it's one of $element parent, but wich ?), wich div is fixed ?

Comment: i have added the css for more clarification you can have a look now @Nomis

Comment: my sincere apologies i have adjusted the html and provided the working fiddle please have a look!

Comment: i did tried but its not working it is not scrolling!

Comment: It was probably because `taketotop` was called twice. I edited again with a better solution.

Comment: this worked! but one last concern i have to minus 250 from the offset then it came to the correct position of every error element, why the difference of 250(approx) where seems to be the miscalculation?

Comment: Are you sure you call `taketotop` only once ? If you call it at each test, you'll end up at the last field tested, and since you test from top to bottom, you'll end up just before the last incorrect field. Add the `if($flag)` condition before each `taketotop` call or test your fields from bottom to top to solve it. If it's not that I can't say, I don't have such a difference in the JSFiddle.

Comment: yes i did i tested it with only one condition but it still leaves some space

Comment: Well, then we'll need another fiddle to help you (sorry about that ^^) : since the first one doesn't have this issue it's coming from elsewhere and we can't track the bug without a test case.

Comment: You're welcome ! Always a pleasure to help (and all the more if you're willing to help us help you ^^).